# merge two table into a third using INNER JOIN

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access

I'm using MS-Access, trying to merge two tables into a third:

from the table "dbHoldings" that have the following fields:

(ID,isin,Code_BB,Name_BB,asset_name,Weighs,DataDiEstrazione)

togheter with table "dbSecurities2":

(ID,isin,fldName,blkName,fldValue)

into table "dbAssetGroup" with fields:

(ID,isin,Code_BB,Name_BB,asset_name,BB_Weighs,fieldName,bulkName,Bulkweight,allocationWeight,DataDiEstrazione)

I'm receiving the run-Time error '3131'
This is my attempt :

```
strSQL = "INSERT INTO dbAssetGroup(isin, Code_BB, Name_BB, asset_name, BB_Weighs, fieldName, bulkName, fldValue, DataDiEstrazione) " & _                     
"SELECT H.isin, H.Code_BB, H.Name_BB, H.asset_name, H.Weighs, S.fldName, S.blkName, S.fldValue, H.DataDiEstrazione " & _                       
        "FROM " & _                                                 
        "dbHoldings AS H " & _                                               
        "INNER JOIN dbSecurities2 AS S " & _                                           
        "ON H.isin=S.isin) "  
                         
db.Execute strSQL
```

Comment: Is the ) at the end matched?

Comment: you right doesn't mach neither...

Comment: Why are you building SQL in VBA without any concatenation of VBA variables? Consider using a saved query which would be more readable, maintainable, and efficient since Access engine compiles best execution plan especially with `JOIN` for saved queries. Plus, you cannot save a query with syntax errors!

Comment: thanks Parfait I will try using query then... What do you mean "building SQL in VBA without any concatenation of VBA variables?" could you argue more please?

Comment: sorry but I did not specify that this is a VBA in excel communicating with Access to store data

Comment: I think Parfait wondered why you would build an SQL statement in VBA that does not have dynamic parameters. Parameters that would be provided by concatenating variables into constructed SQL statement. Since this SQL does not have variable inputs, could be a query object in Access and Excel VBA calls the query object instead of building SQL statement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give a try to this:

```
strSQL = "INSERT INTO dbAssetGroup(isin, Code_BB, Name_BB, asset_name, BB_Weighs, fieldName, bulkName, fldValue, DataDiEstrazione) " & _                     
"SELECT H.isin, H.Code_BB, H.Name_BB, H.asset_name, H.Weighs, S.fldName, S.blkName, 
S.fldValue, H.DataDiEstrazione " & _                       
        "FROM " & _                                                 
        "dbHoldings AS H " & _                                               
        "INNER JOIN dbSecurities2 AS S " & _                                           
        "ON H.isin=S.isin "  
                     
db.Execute strSQL
```